# Finding cell value at maximum difference

Tags: matlab, max, return-value

I have a spreadsheet of data about cells I've been culturing that I've imported into Matlab. I have a column for the cell size when grown under condition 1 (Si), and a column for cell size when grown under condition 2 (Aq). I've calculated the difference in cell size at each time point. I used the max function to work out the maximum difference in cell size during growth. But how do I recall the cell size for either condition at the max cell size difference?

```
DinoGrowth = xlsread('Dino_growth.xls'); %import data from spreadsheet
G1_Si_size=DinoGrowth(:,4); % size of cells grown in Si over time
G1_Aq_size=DinoGrowth(:,8); % size of cells grown in Aq over time
G1_size_diff=(G1_Aq_size-G1_Si_size); %difference in cell size over time
G1_size_diff_max=max(G1_size_diff); %maximum value of cell size difference (returns a singular value)
```

How do I find the exact value of G1_Si_size and G1_Aq_size where the condition G1_size_diff_max is met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[max](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) can return two values. The first is the value of the maximum and the second is position of the maximum. Use the second output to extract the desired elements.

```
[G1_size_diff_max , idx] =max(G1_size_diff);
result_Si = G1_Si_size(idx);
result_Aq = G1_Aq_size(idx);
```